# Split when a character is found ( txt not delimited) using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, split

I am trying to populate a datagrid from a .txt file. I managed to do it with the split function Split(sr.ReadLine, " ") when I have all the rows identical with only one space, but the problem I have is that the txt file is not delimited and the "spaces" varies some time. This is a sample of my data:

```
Col1  Col2 Col3
1      Mary Yes
1234   John Yes
999    Leo No
```

So my question is how to delimit or split the line based when it finds the next character and ignore the empty spaces. This is the code I have.

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text File|*.txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Open File..."
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "test"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim srlineitems() As String
        srlineitems = Split(sr.ReadLine, " ")

        Dim DT As New DataTable
        DT.Columns.Add("Col1")
        DT.Columns.Add("Col2")
        DT.Columns.Add("Col3")
        DT.Columns.Add("Col4")

        DataGridView1.DataSource = DT

        Dim Lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

        For Each Line As String In Lines
            Dim ItemsOf() As String = Split(Line, " ")
            Dim NRow As String() = {ItemsOf(0), ItemsOf(1), ItemsOf(2), ItemsOf(3)}

            DT.Rows.Add(NRow)

        Next Line


    End If
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the .Net [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method instead, it has a [RemoveEmptyEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) option.

```
ItemsOf = Line.Split(New String() {" "},
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```